# How execute a shell script which is in my git repository through azure cli

Tags: git, shell, azure, azure-cli

This is for my project where I should execute scripts present in git. We should use azure cli to execute scripts in git.

Comment: Where are your scripts? And if you just want to execute extension scripts with azure cli?

Comment: My scripts are in git repository under a folder called test. I want to run those scripts eg: demo.sh. I should perform this action through azure cli. Those scripts in git will perform the actions is azure eg: creating a vm.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to execute a customscript on an VM.

an Example would be:

```
az vm extension set \
  --resource-group exttest \
  --vm-name exttest \
  --name customScript \
  --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions \
  --protected-settings '{"fileUris": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/dotnet-core-sample-templates/master/dotnet-core-music-linux/scripts/config-music.sh"],"commandToExecute": "./config-music.sh"}'
```

See az extension example:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux

Comment: Is there a way to download all the files from github repository into the linux machine. I tried with the above command where fileUris was set to a github file(script) url then running the command resulted in 404 error in one of the log file.

Comment: You can use command: `wget path` download the files from GitHub repository into the Linux machine.